# MySQL Trigger to generate a hash for an auto_increment index

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that generates and store a hash for the auto_increment index but all solutions I've tried did not work:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER insertTable1 AFTER INSERT ON Table1
FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
     SET NEW.hash = calc_hash_udf(NEW.id);
   END //
DELIMITER ;;
```

It says I cannot modify a `NEW` after the `INSERT`, and before the `INSERT` I don't have the `auto_increment` value:

ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'Table1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Could you run an update of the row instead? (not so sure about mutating tables...)

Comment: No it generates an error in the creation of the trigger.

Comment: For personal reference, what is the error?

Comment: ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'Table1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Ok. Since your hash is always deterministic why not dropping the column and having a view for the table like: `select calc_hash_udf(id) as hash, * from Table1`? Otherwise I could think of a job updating the table's hashes every x minutes but that's ugly, and probably not matching your requirements

Comment: It could work, but I'd have to change this in many place of other code that uses the database. I'm using the job trick right now. The trigger would be an improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot modify the value anymore *after* the row was inserted. Therefore `SET NEW.column` is only available in a `BEFORE` trigger.

Also you cannot use a regular `UPDATE` either [because](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

Finally, in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value has not been generated yet, and `NEW.id` is `0`.

The trick: in a `BEFORE` trigger, manually check the table definition for the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value:

## WARNING: this only works with MyISAM, not with InnoDB

*I **suppose** it could work with InnoDB if `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` but I am unable to tell for sure.*

```
DELIMITER //    

    CREATE TRIGGER insertTable1 BEFORE INSERT ON Table1 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE next_ai INT;
        SELECT auto_increment INTO next_ai
          FROM information_schema.tables
          WHERE table_schema=DATABASE() AND table_name = 'Table1';
        SET NEW.hash = calc_hash_udf(next_ai);
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

[edit 1]

As for the concurrent-proof property of this approach, I can say:

- with MyISAM, where only table-locks are available, the safety is obvious: an exclusive lock on the table(s) is acquired by any `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`, and no concurrent access can happen.
- with InnoDB, this is less obvious. For the "[traditional lock mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html)", the manual says:

> InnoDB uses a special lock called the table-level AUTO-INC lock for
>   inserts into tables with AUTO_INCREMENT columns. This lock is normally
>   held to the end of the statement

I suppose this is safe in this case.

I am not familiar with these concepts, so I couldn't tell for sure. It seems dubious indeed.

[edit 2]

I have run the below test with different settings for [`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoinc_lock_mode):

CREATE TABLE t (
    ai INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    trigval INT,
    flag BOOL
);

A trigger on the table does `SET NEW.trigval = next_ai` with the method above.

In one transaction, a long INSERT is made by:

```
INSERT INTO t SELECT null, null, 0 FROM (SELECT * FROM a_very_big_table) AS tmp;
```

In a second transaction, I constantly issue the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (null, null, 1);
```

At the end, I search for discrepancies:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ai <> trigval;
```

With `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0` ("traditional") it seems to be safe. Any concurrent attempt to insert into the table is locked until completion of the long `INSERT`.

However, I did not expect that, with modes `1` (the default) and `2`, this approach is **plainly wrong**. `information_schema.tables.auto_increment` is updated by steps. This is the result I got:

```
+-------+---------+------+
| ai    | trigval | flag |
+-------+---------+------+
|     3 |       4 |    0 |
|     5 |       8 |    0 |
|     9 |      16 |    0 |
|    17 |      32 |    0 |
|    33 |      64 |    0 |
|    65 |     128 |    0 |
...
```

Comment: Just a curiosity is this safe when multiple sources are making Inserts?

Comment: @ppaulojr I was asking myself the same question, and I am not sure. Please check my last edit. I will keep searching because this is bugging me. Stay tuned.

Comment: @ppaulojr I knew it was too easy. Please see my edit. Do not use with InnoDB. Sorry for this mostly wrong answer, feel free to un-accept it.

Comment: I suppose there's no solution for InnoDB?

Comment: There may be, but I do not know. Again, feel free to reopen your question, so that others might jump in with alternatives. I will keep thinking about it, but I have nothing to offer for now, sorry.